# How to convert a list to a multiline string in terraform?

Tags: terraform, argocd

I'm using `ArgoCD` and one of the config params for `RBAC` accepts a CSV block i.e

```
policy.csv: |
    p, role:org-admin, applications, *, */*, allow
    p, role:org-admin, clusters, get, *, allow
```

I'd like to provide a `.tfvars` file with a list of strings i.e

`["p, role:org-admin, applications, *, */*, allow","p, role:org-admin, clusters, get, *, allow"]`

And have it convert the list into a multiline CSV output like above, any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly do you create those lines? Each line have different number of elements. Why not make list of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the simple `join` function

Code to use in terraform file (.tf)

```
locals {
policy_csv = join("\n", var.policies)
}
```

```
> join("\n",["p, role:org-admin, applications, *, */*, allow","p, role:org-admin, clusters, get, *, allow"])
**output**
<<EOT
p, role:org-admin, applications, *, */*, allow
p, role:org-admin, clusters, get, *, allow
EOT
```

If you want to add ***few spaces at the start*** use below.

```
# String Output
> join("\n", formatlist("    <Add Black Spaces> %s",tolist(["p, role:org-admin, applications, *, */*, allow","p, role:org-admin, clusters, get, *, allow"])))
**Output**
<<EOT
    p, role:org-admin, applications, *, */*, allow
    p, role:org-admin, clusters, get, *, allow
EOT
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`join`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/join) function:

```
locals {
  policy_csv = join("\n", var.policy_list)
}
```

Comment: How does this create multiple lines with different element lengths?

Comment: It joins the multiple lines into a single line, separating each of the original lines by a newline. OPs starting state is a simple list where each element is an entire line, so all that is required is to put newline characters between them.